# Multi-threaded C# for responsive GUI with complex background calculations - async / await, TPL, or both?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have a single-threaded program which executes complex, time consuming calculations and reports the progress of these.

```
    private void BtnExecute_Click()
    {
        ComplexCalculation(Object1);
        ComplexCalculation(Object2);
        ComplexCalculation(Object3);
    }
```

The ComplexCalculation method looks like this:

```
private void ComplexCalculation(Object MyObject)
{
   (...do some time consuming operation on MyObject...);
   WriteToTextboxGUI("50% Complete" + MyObject.Name);
   (...do another time consuming operation on MyObject...);
   WriteToTextboxGUI("100% Complete" + MyObject.Name);
}
```

In the above code, the `WriteToTextboxGUI(string)` method updates a textbox on the GUI with the progress.

I'm looking to adopt a multi-threaded approach so that the GUI remains responsive while the complex calculations are carried out. I have read up quite a bit about `BackgroundWorker` and `Threads` in general, and then how this was simplified/improved when `Task` and TPL came onto the scene with .Net 4.0, and now how `Async` and `Await` have arrived with .Net 4.5, and would like to know if these more recent technologies can allow me to re-write my application (in relatively simple code) so that it can:

- Use multiple threads simultaneously to execute complex calculations
- Report progress to my GUI as before
- Maintain a responsive GUI throughout

Can anyone can point me in the direction of a simple solution which would satisfy these three criteria?

P.S. This application will not be running on a server, it will be running in WPF on the desktop.

Comment: why not simply use a background worker?

Comment: Will BackgroundWorker be capable of initiating a thread for each of the three complex tasks, so that all three can be executed simultaneously?

Comment: 3 background workers would be able to....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend that you use `IProgress<T>` for progress reports and `Task.Run` to start background tasks. I recently finished a blog series showing that [`Task.Run` is superior to `BackgroundWorker`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/search/label/Task.Run%20vs%20BackgroundWorker).

In your case:

```
private sealed class ComplexCalculationProgress
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int PercentComplete { get; set; }
}

private void ComplexCalculation(Object MyObject, IProgress<ComplexCalculationProgress> progress)
{
  (...do some time consuming operation on MyObject...);
  if (progress != null)
    progress.Report(new ComplexCalculationProgress { Name = MyObject.Name, PercentComplete = 50 });
  (...do another time consuming operation on MyObject...);
  if (progress != null)
    progress.Report(new ComplexCalculationProgress { Name = MyObject.Name, PercentComplete = 100 });
}
```

Note that since your background operation no longer calls `WriteToTextboxGUI`, it has better separation of concerns. You'll find that the design of `IProgress<T>` encourages a better design in your own code.

You can call it (using simple parallelism) as such:

```
private async void BtnExecute_Click()
{
  var progress = new Progress<ComplexCalculationProgress>(update =>
  {
    WriteToTextboxGUI(update.PercentComplete + "% Complete " + update.Name);
  });
  await Task.WhenAll(
    Task.Run(() => ComplexCalculation(Object1, progress)),
    Task.Run(() => ComplexCalculation(Object2, progress)),
    Task.Run(() => ComplexCalculation(Object3, progress))
  );
}
```

Alternatively, you can easily use "real" parallelism:

```
private async void BtnExecute_Click()
{
  var progress = new Progress<ComplexCalculationProgress>(update =>
  {
    WriteToTextboxGUI(update.PercentComplete + "% Complete " + update.Name);
  });
  var objects = new[] { Object1, Object2, Object3 };
  await Task.Run(() =>
      Parallel.ForEach(objects, o => ComplexCalculation(o, progress))
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am also reading your blog that you linked to, which I find truly excellent.

Answer (score 0):

Background workers can do all this easily.

> Use multiple threads simultaneously to execute complex calculations

Use a new background worker for each calculation.

> Report progress to my GUI as before

Use WorkerReportsProgress=True, with the ReportProgress() method and ProgressChanged event.

> Maintain a responsive GUI throughout

Yep.